# Triangular box character used in tmux config

Tags: tmux, special-characters

On the [wemux readme](https://github.com/zolrath/wemux/blob/master/README.md), there is this image:

[image: wemux]

That's a pretty cool status bar he has there. I can see how it's been done - there's a character that looks something like this:

```
\
##\
####\
######\
#######>
######/
####/
##/
/
```

However, I can't work out what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: Since it extends beyond the height of the other characters I'd guess it isn't a character glyph. Unicode has some [triangular shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Geometric_Shapes) but I doubt they are the source of what you are seeing.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick It doesn't. There's a solid background behind the character, which makes it appear full height. Look closely - you can see the sharp corners where the character stops short of the background.

Comment: My eyesight isn't that good, maybe you can magnify a section of the image by about 10 :-) (see also edit to my prior comment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at his `.tmux.conf`:
https://github.com/zolrath/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf

In particular at the `status-*` style options.

His theme is based on vim's powerline, with a special patched font, see: https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline.

Answer (score 3):

Unicode has some [triangular shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Geometric_Shapes)

[image: 25BC Black Right-pointing triangle]